# Предлагаю удалить девять ошибочных меток

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Предлагаю удалить ненужные (ошибочные) метки:

"заметно", "большая", "существенных", "специальная", "пкнктуация", "изменений",   "порядок" — присутствовали в одном вопросе (каждая);
"выражения" — в двух; "сложные" — в четырёх.

Вопросы с этими метками были отредактированы 19 и 20 июня (неправильные метки заменены — на соответствующие тематике вопросов).

Comment: @Aer Ну вот, получилось. Спасибо. А я уж, было, посчитала себя бестолковой.

Comment: Нет-нет, это система барахлит. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все отмеченные вами метки были удалены. Я также сделал их синонимичными метке [недопустимая-метка](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0), чтобы они были заметнее, если вдруг кто-то применит их снова.

Метка «пкнктуация» теперь будет заменяться на [пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Спасибо вам за помощь в улучшении качества вопросов!

Comment: Я сегодня (по обстоятельствам) занялась ещё описанием меток. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, своим зорким взглядом — все ли в порядке?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова все хорошо! Еще раз спасибо :)